# How to set a default tab in JS

Tags: javascript, tabs

Ok, so I have few tabs made with JS, and it works fine, but how do i set a default tab as landing so i dont have to actually click on it? I mean how to i make my first tab shown by default? Thanks ppl! <3

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just give your first tab the active class in your HTML?

Comment: tried, but then its just link active, and doesn't display the content of the link.

Comment: Did you set the content tab to `display: block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the information given,
it looks like you've posted a function that will be used on click event, effectively resetting all tabs and tab content before activating the desired tab..

this is good but, it says nothing about the state of your tabs before this function is ever called.

to go along with what Jeremy said, you should give your tab the active class in your HTML... You stated that only the tablink is then active...

this is because, by viewing your function, tabcontent and tablinks are different. therefore set both tabcontent AND tablinks to active in your HTML. or be sure that your desired tabcontent is not set initially to display:none

Comment: Wow! this solves my problem! thank you very much! <3